# Liquid template logic to check if a date has no time component? String comparison fails

Tags: date, datetime, if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to get a Liquid condition to run only if `page.date` has a defined time.

Let's say `page.date` is "2019-07-17 00:00:00 -0700".

I found out that the 12-hour (`%r`) time is 12am by default, so I tried this hack (I'm not too worried about a time actually being set by the user to 12:00:00 sharp, causing false positives):

```
{% if page.date | date: "%r" != "12:00:00 AM" %}
    <p>The page's date has a time.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>The page's date has no time.</p>
```

The above block outputs "The page's date has a time.", which is untrue according to my condition (that 12am = "no time").

I also tried the following, with and without `| json` pipes to the right of the `date` formatter:

- `{% if page.date | date: "%T" != "00:00:00" %}`
- `{% if page.date | date: "%R" != "00:00" %}`

Rendering all these formats to a page validates the values I've put in these conditionals, but my string comparisons are still incorrect. Is there a way to do this in Liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter in a condition. `{% if page.date | date: "%r" != "12:00:00 AM" %}` is producing an error.

You can `assign`, then `compare` :

```
{% assign time = page.date | date: "%r" %}

{% if time != "12:00:00 AM" %}
    <p>The page's date has a time.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>The page's date has no time.</p>
{% endif %}
```